# Java 7 exception handling with JDBC Connection and PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, exception, java-7

In the following code-snippet,

1) Does the try-catch block automatically calls "conn.rollback()"  before calling "conn.close()" (by AutoClose)?
If not,do I have to add a `finally { conn.rollback(); }` to that block ?

2) Is the way Connection object passed in to the bar() method ,and the try-catch method in it correct?

```
public void foo() {
        try (Connection conn = datasource.getConnection()) {

            bar(conn, "arg");
            conn.commit();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void bar(Connection conn, String args) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SOME_QUERY")) {
            // Do something
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *try-with-resources* will simply call the `close()` method on the `Connection`. The effect of calling [`Connection.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) when a transaction is active is implementation defined:

> It is **strongly recommended** that an application explicitly commits or rolls back an active transaction prior to calling the `close` method. If the `close` method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined.

In other words: don't depend on it and explicitly call `commit()` or `rollback()` as the actual behavior will vary between drivers, maybe even between versions of the same driver.

Given your example I'd suggest:

```
public void foo() {
    try (Connection conn = datasource.getConnection()) {
        bar(conn, "arg");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void bar(Connection conn, String args) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SOME_QUERY")) {
        // Do something
        ps.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        conn.rollback();
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Since you can't use `conn` in the `catch` or `finally` block of the `try` that created it, you could also nest it:

```
public void foo() {
    try (Connection conn = datasource.getConnection()) {
        try {
            bar(conn, "arg");
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            conn.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the anwer.sorry I forgot to add the commit() in the foo().When does the PreparedStatement created in the bar() methods closes?

Comment: in the link it says : "Note:A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed." So where shall I call "conn.rollback()"? I cannot call it after "conn.close()" is called, can I ?

Comment: You're right, I got that mixed up. But as you can't access the objects created in the try (including the resources) in the catch or finally block, that is not really relevant in this specific case. (I removed my previous comment so I won't confuse anyone else, link was: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html )

Comment: In any case, where you call `commit()` or `rollback()` is not related to the closing of the `PreparedStatement` in `bar()`, which is what your first comment asked for. And given the scope rules, you won't even be able to call those methods after the `conn` has been closed.